# Refactor foreach loops and passing variables in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, arduino

I'm new to C#. I thought I knew a bit of C# but clearly not.

I'm trying to communicate with an Arduino using a C# Windows Form via the serial communication, when the button3 is clicked, the Windows Form app will send a command, for the Arduino to send back the required data, for the Windows Form app to fill in the specified Textboxes, but I'm getting `Error CS0103 The name 'tb' does not exist in the current context` error.

I have tried all possible options provided but with no luck. This is the my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox[] myTextBoxes = new TextBox[] { textBox9, textBox10, textBox11, textBox12, textBox13, textBox14, textBox15, textBox16 };
            String[] myCommands = new String[] { "#TRMMH1\n", "#TRMMM1\n", "#TRMMH2\n", "#TRMMM2\n", "#TRMMH3\n", "#TRMMM3\n", "#TRMMH4\n", "#TRMMM4\n" };
            String inString;

            foreach (String co in myTextBoxes.SelectMany(tb => myCommands))
            {
                port.Write(co);
                inString = port.ReadLine();
                tb.Text = inString;
            }
```

I have tried to search Google and Stack Overflow, but I'm not sure what to search for.

Comment: You do not have a textBox named "tb" on the designer half of your Programm or further up in the class code. You need to use or change the actuall name of the textbox - which represents the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two Size 8 arrays. You can not process two arrays in that way with a foreach - you need a for loop so you can use the running variable for both

```
TextBox[] myTextBoxes = new TextBox[] { textBox9, textBox10, textBox11, textBox12, textBox13, textBox14, textBox15, textBox16 };
String[] myCommands = new String[] { "#TRMMH1\n", "#TRMMM1\n", "#TRMMH2\n", "#TRMMM2\n", "#TRMMH3\n", "#TRMMM3\n", "#TRMMH4\n", "#TRMMM4\n" };

for(int i=0; i<myTextBoxes.Lenght && i<myCommands.Lenght; i++){
    TextBox curTB = myTextBoxes[i];
    String curCMD = myCommands[i];
   
    port.Write(curCMD);
    string temp = port.ReadLine();
    curTB.Text = temp;
}
```

I did not run this code, so off-by-one or syntax errors are to be expected.

Comment: Thank you so much Christopher! This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish with the _foreach_ loop.